# how I can get The last time the file is opened in php

Tags: php

How can I get the last time the file was opened in PHP?

Can anyone help me?

I just found the `stat()` function but this just returns time of last modification but I need last time the file was opened.

Comment: surely you can Google that

Comment: Last time its opened is impossible, as this is not recorded. Possibly you could process the Apache access log to find the last time it was requested by someone, but that wont help you with any non web server access

Comment: Provide some more sample code, add some more details to your question so that we would be more willing to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `fileatime()`.

The following example:

```
<?php
    $filename = "/Users/rafaelalmeida/projects/UFP-API/README.md";

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "$filename was last accessed: " . date("F d Y H:i:s.", fileatime($filename));
    }
```

The result from the code above is: `/Users/rafaelalmeida/projects/UFP-API/README.md was last accessed: February 17 2017 00:29:20.`.

You can read more about `fileatime()` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php).

Comment: Well... this might not really do what the OP wants, since it checks the file, then lists the access, which will be when it was checked - ie, always return the current time. If you want to be able to see when the file was LAST accessed, you will need to always log this to a database or file, then pull the last entry in the file/database.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie actually no. I've changed to another file and the output I get is `/Users/rafaelalmeida/projects/UFP-API/phpunit.xml was last accessed: February 09 2017 20:06:18.`

Comment: @rafaelcpalmeida Are you responsible for every access? If so, you might want to look into the [touch](http://php.net/touch) function. **Edit:** Woops, I thought you were OP for a minute. Regardless, touch updates the access time.

Comment: @thordarson it happens :) I guess that the `touch` function doesn't solve the OP problem because, from what I read, he wants to get the last time that a given file was access